# Stemming that avoids matching popular words with different meanings

Tags: php, nlp, stemming, lemmatization

I'm currently using the PorterStemmer to identify derived words. However, I'm facing an issue with words that don't have the same meaning but appear to have. For example:
`Market` and `Marketing`
`Wine` and `Winning`
etc..
have different meanings, but the PorterStemmer identifies them as the same.

Which open tools are able to overcome such issues? A dictionary with corner-cases? A more advanced stemmer?

Preferably something that is easily accessible through PHP.

Comment: Did you find something in PHP ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't find anything yet. If you do, please update me also.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with stemmers, because they operate on a phonetic basis without any knowledge of the language. You need a lemmatizer. I mostly use the [Java-based Stanford CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml), but I am sure there must be something in PHP.